# Does modules index file get loaded into memory

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In the case of:

```
export * from "./function-file'
export * from "./second-func-file'
export * from "./third-component'
```

inside a folder's index file. My question is, are there any performance drawbacks from doing:

`import {function} from dir-index`

as opposed to requiring each file separately: `const func = require("file")`

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is; *are there **measurable** performance drawbacks*

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/102446)

Comment: The whole point of that index.js file is to have a single defined entry point, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, does it do that at the expense of any performance metric? And thanks @liam this is me just wondering about the underpinnings

Comment: Is this web based Javascript or node? Are you tranpilling it to ECMA5 at all? If yes what transpiller are you using.